# json_decode odd issue

Tags: php, json

I have some very odd issue,

I'm trying to parse some json string with php, string is in array, and if I use simple

```
json_decode($my_array[0],true)
```

it doesn't work, but, if I just copy a string from var_dump($my_array) and try to decode it works 100% ok.

Any ideas what could be wrong ?

Json string:

```
 {"mode":"view","pid":"243","documentId":"193"}
```

Comment: What exactly it doesn't work? What are you expecting?

Comment: "*doesn't work*" is meaningless.

Comment: My guess is that your JSON string has some unexpected invisible (white space) characters that are causing it to be invalid JSON in the first case, but aren't being carried across when you copy+paste it, and thus the copied+pasted version works.

Comment: "doesn't work" means I don't get any return object/array/string/anything , if I make var_dump(json_decode($my_array[0],true)) I just get int(0).

Comment: `0` is something, not nothing.

Comment: SDC I thought about it too, how can I show all that white spaces ?

Comment: Even with whitespace the `json_decode()` will work. Can we see the `var_dump()` of your `my_array`, then? Maybe index of 0 is not what you think it is...

Comment: this json string is in large array, but I'm 100% sure that index is OK. I've checked json_decode without true param, and I get "NULL"  in var_dump, and in json_last_error() I get "4"

Comment: JSON Error 4 means Syntax Error. You can test your JSON string with [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com).

Comment: Ok, I couldn't find this syntax error so I have use other approach, that is, I put to this script data not in JSON format but serialized in PHP ( a:3:{s:4:"mode";s:4:"view";s:3:"pid";s:3:"261";s:10:"documentId";s:3:"347";} ) now I get this notice: Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 5 of 136 bytes , any ideas? and still, the same behavior, if I copy this manually it works ....

Answer (score 2):

Kuba,

Here's the syntax for converting a json array into a php associative array:

```
$my_array = '{"mode":"view","pid":"243","documentId":"193"}';
$new_array = json_decode($my_array,true);

echo $new_array['mode']; //return: view
echo $new_array['pid']; //return: 243
echo $new_array['documentId']; //return: 193
```

**var_dump() result:**

```
array (size=3)
  'mode' => string 'view' (length=4)
  'pid' => string '243' (length=3)
  'documentId' => string '193' (length=3)
```

Comment: I know syntax and how to do it, I've used it couple of times ;-) It seems that It could be something about white spaces (as SDC said in comments)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the solution, after data serialization I've encoded string using base64_encode and then push It in that form to other scripts.

I still don't know why I had to encode it with base64, maybe because this string is used in javascript scripts and after that decoded in php?